# Sudoku solving in java using backtrack

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to write a sudoku solver using java. I have used a common backtrack algorithm for it. But the program isn't working properly(returning null)

Here's the code

```
public class Sudoku {

    int[][] board;                                                              //Sudoku board


    public Sudoku() {                                                           //constructor
        this.board = new int[9][9];             
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                board[i][j]=0;
    }

    public Sudoku(int[][] board){                                               //constructor
        this.board=board;
    }


    public int[][] Solve(int[][] board){
        int i, j, k,l,val;                                                      //iterators 
        int empty=1;                                                            //empty flag
        int[][] temp=new int[9][9];                                             //temporary array for backtracking
        temp=board;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)                                                        //check if any empty space available
            for(j=0;j<9;j++){
                if(board[i][j]==0){
                    empty=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if(empty==1)return board;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
            outerLoop:
            for(j=0;j<9;j++){
                if(board[i][j]>0)continue;
                for(val=1;val<10;val++){                                        //try values
                    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
                        if(board[i][k]==val)break;                              //check row consistancy 
                        if(board[k][j]==val)break;                              //check column consistancy     
                    }
                    for(k=(i/3)*3;k<(i/3+1)*3;k++)                              //check latin square consistancy
                        for(l=(j/3)*3;l<((j/3+1)*3);l++)
                            if(board[k][l]==val)break;                      
                    temp[i][j]=val;                                             //put consistant value
                    Solve(temp);                                                //recursive call for backtrack
                }
        }
        return null;                                                            
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[][] board={ {5,3,0,0,7,0,0,0,0},
                        {6,0,0,1,9,5,0,0,0},
                        {0,9,8,0,0,0,0,6,0},
                        {8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,3},
                        {4,0,0,8,0,3,0,0,1},
                        {7,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,6},
                        {0,6,0,0,0,0,2,8,0},
                        {0,0,0,4,1,9,0,0,5},
                        {0,0,0,0,8,0,0,7,9}};
        Sudoku s=new Sudoku(board);
        int[][] temp=new int[9][9];
        temp=s.Solve(board);
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            System.out.println("");
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                System.out.print(temp[i][j]);
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

I put the null return statement due to netbeans suggestions, but it's supposed to never return null. I can't find the mistake. Thanks in advance for your ind help.

Comment: Your Solve(int[][] board) function is not really readable. Perhaps you should try first to indent it correctly. You should also remember that your Solve function returns the board, it would be a good idea to keep in your recursive call. 
Eventually, your function is returning null because there is no other return instructions after recursively solving the board. It needs a bit of rework before going any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to focus on your `Solve(int[][])` method:

```
public int[][] Solve(int[][] board){
```

Under Java naming conventions, methods should be camelCase: `solve(int[][] board)`

```
    int i, j, k,l,val;
```

Unless necessary, you shouldn't define your iterators at the beginning of a method.  It gives them a 'false sense of purpose', making the code harder to interpret.

```
    int empty=1;
```

This should be a boolean because it only ever holds a value of 1 or 0.  A boolean value would be much more readable here: `boolean empty = false;`

```
    int[][] temp=new int[9][9];                                             
    temp=board;
```

Also, I advise breaking up your code into 'paragraphs', or related operations.  This would be a good spot for a new paragraph as you move from definitions to some initial logic.

```
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)                                                        
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            if(board[i][j]==0){
                empty=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(!empty)return board;
```

This should be its own paragraph as it handles a single task, checking if the board is solved.  I have also updated it to show how booleans read better.

```
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        outerLoop:
        for(j=0;j<9;j++){
            if(board[i][j]>0)continue;
            for(val=1;val<10;val++){                                        
                for(k=0;k<9;k++){
                    if(board[i][k]==val)break;                               
                    if(board[k][j]==val)break;                                  
                }
                for(k=(i/3)*3;k<(i/3+1)*3;k++)                              
                    for(l=(j/3)*3;l<((j/3+1)*3);l++)
                        if(board[k][l]==val)break;                      
                temp[i][j]=val;                                             
                Solve(temp);                                                
            }
    }
    return null;                                                            
}
```

Your code has two return statements, one for a finished board and one that catches logic errors.  The error is in your recursive call.  Just calling `Solve(temp);` will not preserve any changes you've made to the data.  A recursive function only works if you use the new information generated by the recursive call.  Therefore, to fix your error, return your recursive call:

```
return Solve(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I'm kinda newbee to programming and don't have much experience with java. If I return Solve(temp) in the place of I get StackOverflowError.

Comment: That means that it is taking too many steps to solve.  What you have here is a special case called tail call recursion, meaning that you only make one recursive call and it is at the very end.  Fortunately for you, there is an easy fix to the overflow.  Instead of using a recursive function, encompass your logic in a while loop that breaks:
`if (!empty) break;`
Basically every time you make a function call inside a function, the computer has to keep track of where you were so when the function call finishes, you continue where you left off.  This is called the call stack and it has a limit.

Comment: Java is a good language for many things, but mathematical algorithms like these are well-suited for functional languages like F#. (which automatically converts tail call recursion to iteration for you) Stick to Java for learning, but keep this in mind if you intend to do a lot of mathematical programming.